# Where to start for Tech Specs of an IT project.. more specifically functional specifications

Tags: documentation-generation

Hi I'm wonderingif someone knows some good resources on writing project specs.

I'm a freelance developer more focused on actual development and less focused
on tech specs.

I'm involved in a proj where have to write technical
specs (& functional req specs) and have absolutely no idea where to
start.. any good site or sample or book you would advise ?

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend User Stories Applied by Mike Cohn

Answer (score 0):

Any non-trivial project requires Tech Spec. By non-trivial I mean more than about 1 week of coding or more than 1 programmer.
Although there no much resources online which may help to realize how to make good Tech Specs. So Let me share my vision in this field.
Every spec should contain:

- List item
- Title
- Overview (general words what about the project is)
- Operational purpose (what for the project is, the goal)
- Functional purpose (the ways and technical methods/resources attained for fulfilling Operational purpose)
- Definitions (to avoid polysemy and for clarification purposes)
- DATA AND LISTS (the most important and the biggest part of Tech Spec. The section where described data structures, relational database models, choice of programming languages and tools, algorithms, etc)
- Wireframes and pages descriptions
- Technical requirements (hosting conditions, system requirements, etc)
- Сommissioning and acceptance conditions (all criteria which make your job completed)